# Deploy a Java Applet with Security Permission in HTML

Tags: java, html, security, applet, embed

I am having an extremely difficult time getting this to work.

The applet is embed on my [web page](http://boba.dyndns-server.com/Test/) and it is trying to connect to a Java Servlet [here](http://boba.dyndns-server.com:8080/BobaServer/Class_Server/).

On some computers it connects fine, on others I get a can not connect error, which I believe is caused by java security permissions.

> Custom 1: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 184.91.186.5:8080 connect,resolve)

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 184.91.186.5:8080 connect,resolve)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at Calendar_Algorithm$Con.send_courses_to_server(Calendar_Algorithm.java:789)
    at Calendar_Algorithm$Con.run(Calendar_Algorithm.java:773)
    at Calendar_Algorithm.send_courses_to_server(Calendar_Algorithm.java:761)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have signed the jar file, yet it still doesn't fix the issue.
Here is how I generated the key file and signed the jar.

```
keytool -genkey -alias cal -keystore keys  -keypass #### -dname "cn=feldman" -storepass ####

jarsigner -keystore keys -storepass #### -keypass #### -signedjar CalSigned.jar Cal.jar cal
```

Here is how I am embedding it into the html page:

```
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

    <script>
        var attributes = {code:'Calendar_Algorithm.class',
                      archive:'Cal39.jar',
                      width:150, height:50,
                      id:"ClientApp",
                      name:"ClientApp"
                      } ;
        var parameters = {fontSize:16} ;
        var version = '1.6' ;
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
    </script>
```

I also tried doing a jnlp file, and I could not even get that to start the jar, here is my jnlp file content:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.5+" codebase="" href="">
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <information>
        <title>Easy Course Selector</title> 
        <vendor>Group Boba</vendor>
        <homepage href="index.html"/>
        <description>Easy Course Selector</description>
        <description kind="short">Easy Course Selector</description>
        <icon href="mouseguard-small-jpg3.jpg"/>

    </information>

    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <jar href="Cal.jar" main="true" download="eager" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc name="EasyCourse Applet" main-class="Calendar_Algorithm.class" width="200" height="50">
    </applet-desc>
    <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

And the embed code

```
<script> 
    var attributes = {id:"ClientApp", name:"ClientApp", code:'Calendar_Algorithm',   width:150, height:50} ; 
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'Cal_Info.jnlp'} ; 
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6'); 
</script>
```

This is the error log of when I use it to connect to the external server:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 184.91.186.5:8080 connect,resolve)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at Calendar_Algorithm$Con.send_courses_to_server(Calendar_Algorithm.java:789)
at Calendar_Algorithm$Con.run(Calendar_Algorithm.java:773)
at Calendar_Algorithm.send_courses_to_server(Calendar_Algorithm.java:761)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be amazing.

Also here is the code that causes the error:

```
class Con implements PrivilegedExceptionAction<Boolean> {
    private final String text;
    boolean res;
    public Con(String t) {
      text=t;
    }

    public Boolean run() { 
      res=send_courses_to_server();
      return res;
    } 
    public boolean send_courses_to_server(){

        try {
            URL url = new URL(server);

            HttpURLConnection con;
            con=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);


            OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
            String xml="";
            writer.write("<Request>\n" +"<Request_Type>Validation_2</Request_Type>\n");
            xml="<Request>\n" +"<Request_Type>Validation_2</Request_Type>\n";



            Scanner in=new Scanner(text);
            while(in.hasNext()){
                String temp=in.nextLine().trim();
                writer.write("<Course>"+temp+"</Course>\n");
                xml=xml+"<Course>"+temp+"</Course>\n";
            }
            writer.write("</Request>\n");
            xml=xml+"</Request>\n";

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            InputStream is= con.getInputStream();

            if(con.getContentType().equals("text/xml")){
                status_message= new Scanner(is).nextLine();
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return set_courses(is);
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            status_message= "Custom 1: "+e.getMessage();
            return false;
        }

    }

    private boolean set_courses(InputStream is){
        courses=new Vector<Course>();

        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(is);

            Course c;
            while(true){
                try{
                    c=(Course)ois.readObject();
                    courses.add(c);
                }catch(EOFException e){
                    break;
                }
            }
            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            status_message= "Custom 3 "+e.getMessage();
            return false;
        }
        status_message="Good";
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the exception you are getting? Also, your JNLP file seems a bit minimal.

Comment: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 184.91.186.5:8080 connect,resolve)
I had to switch OS to get the error, that IP is the IP of the servlet

Comment: @Paulo Ebermann, I have had trouble finding a good guide for the jnlp file, can u give me some suggestions to improve mine?

Comment: The interesting part would be the stack trace, i.e. where the exception occurs. Instead of `e.getMessage()` do a `e.printStackTrace()` and have a look at the Java console. (And add it to the question, not as a comment.)

Comment: Okay, now your jnlp file is visible (hint: add 4 spaces to indent the code, then the engine does not try to interpret the tags as HTML). The `applet-desc` element should name the same applet class which you would use in the "usual" case. For more information, look at the [Applet Deployment](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) part of the Java tutorial.

Comment: I added the stack trace, I will look into that doc u posted

Comment: I added a stack trace from when the error is thrown when using the first tag. I also added the error when I try to use the jnlp file.
I really appreciate the help

Comment: Umm the 4 spaces is that just on the post or should I add 4 spaces to my jnlp file?

Comment: I got the jnlp file working, however I still get the same error that I get when I use the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, with the stack trace we can see the reason a bit better.

```
...
at Calendar_Algorithm$Con.send_courses_to_server(Calendar_Algorithm.java:789)
at Calendar_Algorithm$Con.run(Calendar_Algorithm.java:773)
at Calendar_Algorithm.send_courses_to_server(Calendar_Algorithm.java:761)
...
at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
...
```

You are using JavaScript to invoke a method of your applet, it seems. The `send_courses_to_server` method of your `CalendarAlgorithm` class is invoked from JavaScript, and invokes directly the `run` method of your `Con` inner class. This means that your code runs with (only) the permissions of the outer JavaScript, not with the permissions of your applet.

The `Con` class extends `PrivilegedExceptionAction`, but this alone is not enough to give privileged execution. You must also wrap this in a call to  `AccessController.doPrivileged(...)` (here give your `Con` object).

Then the method will be called with the privileges given to your applet by signing. (Of course, you should check before that this call is legitimate and does nothing evil.)

Here I suppose your signing works, I did not check this, as I'm normally working with unsigned applets. By the way, if your applet comes from the same server as the servlet is on, this connection should not need any signing.

Comment: So if I do this:
public boolean send_courses_to_server(String t){
  con.set_text(t);
  AccessController.doPrivileged(con.run());
  return con.res;
 }, it should work? 
or do u mean when I make the call from JavaScript?

Comment: No, do `return AccessController.doPrivileged(con);`. You do not have to call the `run` method yourself, the AccessController will do this.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that with that change I don't need the jnlp file? If their a benefit to one over the other?

Comment: The JNLP file is simply another (newer) way to do this. There are some properties which are only settable with the JNLP file, and a unsigned JNLP applet has access to the JNLP API (for local access with approval by the user), while a standard applet doesn't (on the Sun VM). IcedTea and the current Mac OS VMs don't seem to support jnlp files (but in IcedTea you nevertheless can access the JNLP API, also with normal applets).